# Why does my neural network perform different on the same images during training and testing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, classification

I use tensorflow to build a neural network that classifies images of covid-19 rapid tests into three classes ([Negative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M53bS.jpg), [Positive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqiRV.jpg), [Empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBLrd.jpg)).

During training the tensorboard logs denote a validation accuracy of around 90%. But when I test the network after being trained with the same images it was trained on, the classification performance is way worse (~60%). I observed the same behavior when I trained the network with different images (see section `What I have tried`).

During training the images are preprocessed to grayscale and resized before being fed into the model. The batch size is 16.

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image = cv2.resize(image, (height, width))
```

To augment the sparse data that I have (~450 images) I am using the `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` and its parameters are: `width_shift_range=0.1`, `brightness_range=[0.9, 1.1]`, `height_shift_range=0.1`, `zoom_range=0.2`, `horizontal_flip=True`, `rotation_range=10`, `shear_range=0.2`, `fill_mode="nearest"`, `samplewise_center=True`, `samplewise_std_normalization=True`

I am converting the model to tflite because we need it for mobile platforms. I am using this code snippet:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model) # path to the SavedModel directory
# converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT] # optimizations
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('rapid_test_strip_cleaned_model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

**What I have tried:**

- crop the images to the [strip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCKtS.jpg) of the casette, train and test the network again
- check in the testing (inference) script if the labels are correct
- check if the images are converted to grayscale and resized correctly before being fed into the network during testing
- test the model before converting it to tflite, using `tensorflow.keras.models`

**Model:**

```
img_width, img_height = (256, 256)

model = Sequential()
inputShape = (img_width, img_height, 1)
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=inputShape))
# to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
# to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
# to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
  
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
# to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation="softmax"))

opt = Adam(learning_rate=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
            metrics=["accuracy"])
```

This is the [Tensorboard graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeWVa.png) of the training. The straight line is from another training run.

**Testing/Inference script:**

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]
width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]

labels = ["positive", "negative", "initial"]

# load image into numpy array
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image = cv2.resize(image, (height, width))
input_arr = img_to_array(image)

input_arr = np.array([input_arr])
# normalize values
input_arr = input_arr / 255.0

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_arr)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

results = np.squeeze(output_data)
top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]

print(labels[top_k[0]])
```

Where may be the problem?

Comment: Are you turning off Dropout during testing?

Comment: I am not. But now that I read up on that, the forum posts say, that keras and tflite turn off Dropout by default. Is that not the case here?

Comment: `input_arr = input_arr / 255.0` Did you also do this for the training images? Your `ImageDataGenerator` doesn't show that you are. If you aren't when training, don't do it when testing.

Comment: `input_arr = img_to_array(image)

input_arr = np.array([input_arr])` is also redundant in this case.

Comment: To `input_arr = input_arr / 255.0`: I am doing that since the ImageDataGenerator has the `samplewise_std_normalization` flag set. I think that normalizes the images, aka subtracting the mean pixel value and dividing the result by the standard deviation of the pixel values. And I thought since it is a grayscale image I just divide it by the standard deviation (255). Is that wrong?

Comment: I found the issue with your tip! It was the normalization in the inference script. It is supposed to be `input_arr = (input_arr - np.mean(input_arr)) / np.std(input_arr)`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with the tip of @Djinn. It was the normalization in the inference script. It is supposed to be `input_arr = (input_arr - np.mean(input_arr)) / np.std(input_arr)`.